# How to open a pop up on cell click in a table using ag-grid react?

Tags: reactjs

Need to open a pop-up along with cell data from DB based on the type on on ag-grid table by using the survey tag id?

I can able to fetch the survey tag id

```
emoji = () =>{
    isPopup()=true;
  }
onCellClicked = event => {
    console.log(event);
    let tag = event.data.survey_tag_id;
    console.log(tag);
    const column = event.colDef;
    if (column.headerName === "emoji" ){
      this.emoji();
    }else{
      this.showNotification("clicked", "success");
    }
    console.log(
      "onCellClicked: " + event.data.name + ", col " + event.colIndex
    );


  };
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this answer can help, but this applies in angular sorry if you can not translate it into the react

parent.html

```
<div >
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 100%; height: 750px; border-radius: 5px; text-align: left;"
        class="ag-theme-balham-dark"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [enableFilter]="true"
        [enableSorting]="true"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
        [animateRows]="true"
        [enableStatusBar]="true"
        [enableColResize]="true"
        [enableRangeSelection]="true"
        [alwaysShowStatusBar]="false"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
```

parent.ts

```
graphAlarm(apn:any): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(graphAlarm, {
      width: '1000px',
      height: '700px',
      data : apn,
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    });
  }

  onCellClicked(event){
    this.graphAlarm(event)
    console.log('get dialog : ',event.data)
  }
```

in this part pop up or dialog in angular material `graphAlarm` child/part from file `parent`

graphAlarm.ts

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'graph-alarm',
      templateUrl: '
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row col-sm-8">
      <div class="col">
        {{name.kpi}}
      </div>
      <div class="col">

          <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button style="border-radius: 10px; background-color: #044c94;color: white" (click)="sendChangeThreshold()">
        save
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="border-radius: 10px;">

      <div class="row" style="font-size: 12px; ">
        <table id="table" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource.nameKPI" class="mat-elevation-z8"
               style="width: 100%; background-color: #230162; color: white;">

          <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="header">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="color: white;"> KPI</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="color: white;"> {{element.header}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="threshold_up">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="color: white; text-align: center;"> Threshold Up | 4G</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <input *ngIf="element.threshold_up && element.header != 'Throughput'"
                     (change)="save(element.header,'up',thresholdUp.value)"
                     style="width: 150px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #230162; color: white;"
                     ngModel="{{element.threshold_up}}" #thresholdUp>
              <input *ngIf="element.threshold_up && element.header == 'Throughput'"
                     style="width: 150px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #230162; color: white;"
                     ngModel="{{element.threshold_up}}" disabled>
              <input *ngIf="element.threshold_up_4g"
                     (change)="save(element.header,'4g up',thresholdUp4G.value)"
                     style="width: 150px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #230162; color: white;"
                     ngModel="{{element.threshold_up_4g}}" #thresholdUp4G>
              <!--                     (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">-->
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- Weight Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="threshold_down">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="color: white; text-align: center;"> Threshold Down | 4G</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <input *ngIf="element.threshold_down && element.header != 'Throughput'"
                     (change)="save(element.header,'low',thresholdDown.value)"
                     style="width: 150px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #230162; color: white;"
                     ngModel="{{element.threshold_down}}" #thresholdDown>
              <!--              (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">-->
              <input *ngIf="element.threshold_down && element.header == 'Throughput'"
                     style="width: 150px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #230162; color: white;"
                     ngModel="{{element.threshold_down}}" disabled>
              <input *ngIf="element.threshold_down_4g"
                     (change)="save(element.header,'4g low',threshold4GDown.value)"
                     style="width: 150px; border-radius: 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #230162; color: white;"
                     ngModel="{{element.threshold_down_4g}}" #threshold4GDown>
              <!--              (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">-->
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="border-radius: 10px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
      <div class="box_down">
        <div class="material-icons" style="font-size: 100px;">note_add</div>
        <input style="padding-bottom: 10px;font-size: 10px;" type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)"
               placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">
        <div class="listFile">
          list file
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="box_down1">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Alarm Triggered</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Telegram Bot Alarm</label>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
',
      styleUrls: ['graph-alarm.scss'],
      animations: [
        trigger('detailExpand', [
          state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0'})),
          state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
          transition(
            'expanded <=> collapsed',
            animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')
          )
        ])
      ]
    })
    export class graphAlarm implements OnInit {


      constructor(
        public apn_service: ApnDashboardService,
        private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<graphAlarm>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public selected_apn: any,
      ) {
        console.log('anu tour', selected_apn.nameKPI);
        this.dataSource = selected_apn;
        this.kpi_threshold_up = selected_apn.threshold_up;
      }


      ngOnInit() {
      }

      onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
```